# Extract multiple div tags with the same name

Tags: javascript, html

How I can extract all 3 values from this HTML with the tag "rating".

I've tried:

```
document.getElementsbyTagName("rating")  
 var ratings = ratingPage.querySelector("div.rating").innerText;
```

This one works, but only for the very first occurrence of "rating".

```
<div class="rating-slider">
          <div class="label">First</div>
          <div class="rating">4.2</div>
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="rate-slider" data-rating="good">
              <div class="ui-slider-range" style="width:83.99999618530273%"></div>
              <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 83.99999618530273%;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rating-slider">
          <div class="label">Second</div>
          <div class="rating">3.4</div>
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="rate-slider"  data-rating="average">
              <div class="ui-slider-range" style="width:68.00000190734863%"></div>
              <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 68.00000190734863%;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rating-slider">
          <div class="label">Third</div>
          <div class="rating">1.9</div>
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="rate-slider" data-rating="poor">
              <div class="ui-slider-range" style="width:37.99999952316284%"></div>
              <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 37.99999952316284%;"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div
```

I'm trying to grab each of them and store them in their own variables.

Comment: You're looking for `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var ratings = document.querySelectorAll("div.rating");`

or

```
var ratings = document.getElementsByClassName("rating"); // preferred`
for(var i = 0; i < ratings.length; i++) {
    console.log(ratings[i].innerText);
}
```

Comment: Your first example worked perfectly! Is there a reason the second one is preferred?

Comment: @jlee Yes, performance, see the test here https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/25 click `Run Tests`

Answer (score 2):

This is because you need to use the [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) function as you seem to be targeting actual classes as opposed to tags  :

```
var ratings = document.getElementsByClassName('rating');
```

If you wanted to store just the values, you could either explicitly iterate through this collection and pull the necessary HTML for each of them :

```
for(var r = 0; r < ratings.length; r++){
    // Set each value using ratings[r].innerHTML;
}
```

Or you could use something fancy like the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to map each of these elements to parsed versions of their values :

```
// This will yield [4.2, 3.4, 1.9]
var actualRatings = Array.prototype.map.call(ratings, function(elem){ 
                       return parseFloat(elem.innerHTML);
                    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this selector:

`document.getElementsByClassName("rating");`

This method will return a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name.

You can read more about this selector and usage on this page [on this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)